# Equivelant of .NET GeoCoordinate.GetDistanceTo in Windows 8 Metro style Apps

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, getdistance

What is the equivelant of the System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate.GetDistanceTo method in Metro style Windows 8 Applications.

Metro applications have the Geocoordinate class (With a lower case 'C') but no GetDistanceTo method.

Secondly, the Metro Geocoordinate class has no constructor. How can I create an instance of it.

Comment: Check out this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geocoordinate#Y0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Metro `Geocoordinate` has no `public` constructor for some reason. The best way to implement this in my opinion is to use Reflector and copy the implementation of `System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate` which will also give you `GetDistanceTo`.

Hopefully this will be re-added to the API at a later time.

Answer (score 26):

I decompiled the .NET 4.5 GetDistanceTo method as per BlackLight. Copying here to save people some effort.

```
public double GetDistanceTo(GeoCoordinate other)
{
    if (double.IsNaN(this.Latitude) || double.IsNaN(this.Longitude) || double.IsNaN(other.Latitude) || double.IsNaN(other.Longitude))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString("Argument_LatitudeOrLongitudeIsNotANumber"));
    }
    else
    {
        double latitude = this.Latitude * 0.0174532925199433;
        double longitude = this.Longitude * 0.0174532925199433;
        double num = other.Latitude * 0.0174532925199433;
        double longitude1 = other.Longitude * 0.0174532925199433;
        double num1 = longitude1 - longitude;
        double num2 = num - latitude;
        double num3 = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(num2 / 2), 2) + Math.Cos(latitude) * Math.Cos(num) * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(num1 / 2), 2);
        double num4 = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(num3), Math.Sqrt(1 - num3));
        double num5 = 6376500 * num4;
        return num5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the result is in meters

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small libary to work with coordinates a year ago or something that can help you calculating distances between coordinates. It's available at CodePlex: http://beavergeodesy.codeplex.com/

Calculating distances is then done as easy as this.

```
// Create a pair of coordinates
GeodeticCoordinate coordinate1 = new GeodeticCoordinate() { Latitude = 63.83451d, Longitude = 20.24655d };
GeodeticCoordinate coordinate2 = new GeodeticCoordinate() { Latitude = 63.85763d, Longitude = 20.33569d };
// Calculate the distance between the coordinates using the haversine formula
double distance = DistanceCalculator.Haversine(coordinate1, coordinate2);
```

Comment: Doesn't that formula assume that earth is spherical?

Comment: Yes, so it isn't the best if you need high precision over long distances. In most cases it will do just fine though.

Comment: I was thinking about using reflector on the .NET version and writing an extension method to do this.

Comment: Also a solution, the algorithm really aren't that hard so it should be quite easy to extract it.