# how to calculate distance between two geographic points

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am developping a UWP application, and now im trying to calculate the distance between two points I alreday have their latitude and longitude .
any ideas how to do that ?

Comment: Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446694/equivelant-of-net-geocoordinate-getdistanceto-in-windows-8-metro-style-apps

Answer (score 0):

```
<maps:Map x:Name="myMap" Tap="ReadMapTap" />
```

And then translate the tap location into a GeoCoordinate like so:

```
void ReadMapTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    GeoCoordinate tapLocation = 
         distanceMap.ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate(e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender));
}
```

Then we just create another GeoCoordinate, like maybe Microsoft campus:

```
GeoCoordinate Msft = new GeoCoordinate(47.6396, -122.1300);
```

And just ask one of our GeoCoordinates how far it is to the other one.

```
double distanceToMSFT = tapLocation.GetDistanceTo(Msft);
MessageBox.Show("It is " + distanceToMSFT.ToString() + " meters from there to Microsoft!");
```

Comment: please let me know if it works for you and dont forget to voteup and accept and an answer if it helps you

Comment: @nawfel So you want the exact method? Sorry nobody is going to do that work for you

Comment: i dont want any method @rahul im looking for how a distance betwwen places could be calculated

Comment: Please note that the GeoCoordinate class you are reffering to is not available in UWP. There is a class called Geocoordinate (without the capital C), but this class has no GetDistanceTo method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geocoordinate.aspx